# Ошибка "self signed certificate" при соединении с imap.gmail.com

Tags: node.js, ssl, imap

Пробую подключиться по imap:

```js
const
  imaps = require("imap-simple");

async function test() {
  await imaps.connect({ imap: {
      "user": "********@gmail.com",
      "password": "*****",
      "host": "imap.gmail.com",
      "port": "993",
      "tls": "true",
      "authTimeout": "3000"
    }
  });

  console.log(`imap.state: ${connection.imap.state}`);

  let boxes = await connection.getBoxes();
  console.log(`Notice: available boxes: ${Object.keys(boxes)}`);
  process.exit();
}

test();
```

Запускаю:

```sh
NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=../ssl/api/GTSR2.pem node test.js
```

Ошибка:

```
events.js:186
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: self signed certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1317:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:792:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:606:12)
    at Socket.ondata (internal/js_stream_socket.js:64:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:305:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at TLSSocket._onError (/home/hub/mailtester/api/node_modules/imap/lib/Connection.js:151:10)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:209:13)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:91:8)
    at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:59:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT',
  source: 'socket'
}
```

То же самое, с `imap.yandex.ru` - работает.

Как подсказал в ответе **Sergey Nudnov**, нужно использовать корневой сертификат `Issuer: OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign` (https://pki.goog/gtsr2/GTSR2.crt) преобразовав его в `pem`.

Я воспользовался этим советом и проверил на NodeJS `12.10.0` (Debian 9), а также `12.13.1` (Alpine Linux в докере) - не работает, та же самая ошибка.

В версии `8.15.1` - работает (выдает предупреждение `cert already in hash table`), в том числе и без указания сертификата. Думаю, потому что сертификат уже находится в хранилище системы. Это навело меня на мысль установить корневые сертификаты как пакет Linux.

Я установил корневые сертификаты:

- Debian 9: `apt install ca-cacert`
- Alpine Linux: `apk add ca-certificates`.

и запускал как `node test.js` - выскакивает та же самая ошибка в обоих случаях.

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 3):

[Рекомендуют](https://github.com/mscdex/node-imap/issues/724) добавить опцию `tlsOptions.servername` в настройки imap-клиента

> tlsOptions: { servername: "imap.gmail.com" }

Например, так:

```
await imaps.connect({
  imap: {
    user: '********@gmail.com',
    password: '*****',
    host: 'imap.gmail.com',
    port: '993',
    tls: 'true',
    tlsOptions: {servername: 'imap.gmail.com'},
    authTimeout: '3000',
  },
});
```

Ещё может помочь опция `tlsOptions.rejectUnauthorized`

> tlsOptions: { rejectUnauthorized: false }

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что за ключ вы пытаетесь здесь использовать. В любом случае - неважно, так как неверно.

Для корректной работы защищённого соединения, клиент должен доверять SSL сертификату, предоставляемому сервером. Сертификат сервера обычно подписан промежуточным CA сертификатом, а тот, в свою очередь, подписан корневым CA сертификатом. Получается цепочка сертификатов: сертификат сервера <- один или несколько промежуточных сертификатов <- корневой сертификат.

Для того, чтобы проверить данную цепочку, клиент должен знать и иметь корневой сертификат. Наиболее известные корневые сертификаты клиент, в данном случае node.js, обычно берёт из файла, поставляемого при его установке. Неизвестные корневые сертификаты могут быть предоставлены клиенту другим способом. Для node.js - через отдельный файл, прописанный через переменную окружения `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` (см. [документацию](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_extra_ca_certs_file))

Корневой сертификат, используемый imap.gmail.com:993, может быть получен следующим образом:

1. `openssl s_client -showcerts -connect imap.gmail.com:993`

   берём последний в списке блок между `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` и `-----END CERTIFICATE-----` и записываем в файл `intermediate.pem`:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIESjCCAzKgAwIBAgINAeO0mqGNiqmBJWlQuDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBMMSAw
   HgYDVQQLExdHbG9iYWxTaWduIFJvb3QgQ0EgLSBSMjETMBEGA1UEChMKR2xvYmFs
   U2lnbjETMBEGA1UEAxMKR2xvYmFsU2lnbjAeFw0xNzA2MTUwMDAwNDJaFw0yMTEy
   MTUwMDAwNDJaMEIxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMR4wHAYDVQQKExVHb29nbGUgVHJ1c3Qg
   U2VydmljZXMxEzARBgNVBAMTCkdUUyBDQSAxTzEwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUA
   A4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDQGM9F1IvN05zkQO9+tN1pIRvJzzyOTHW5DzEZhD2ePCnv
   UA0Qk28FgICfKqC9EksC4T2fWBYk/jCfC3R3VZMdS/dN4ZKCEPZRrAzDsiKUDzRr
   mBBJ5wudgzndIMYcLe/RGGFl5yODIKgjEv/SJH/UL+dEaltN11BmsK+eQmMF++Ac
   xGNhr59qM/9il71I2dN8FGfcddwuaej4bXhp0LcQBbjxMcI7JP0aM3T4I+DsaxmK
   FsbjzaTNC9uzpFlgOIg7rR25xoynUxv8vNmkq7zdPGHXkxWY7oG9j+JkRyBABk7X
   rJfoucBZEqFJJSPk7XA0LKW0Y3z5oz2D0c1tJKwHAgMBAAGjggEzMIIBLzAOBgNV
   HQ8BAf8EBAMCAYYwHQYDVR0lBBYwFAYIKwYBBQUHAwEGCCsGAQUFBwMCMBIGA1Ud
   EwEB/wQIMAYBAf8CAQAwHQYDVR0OBBYEFJjR+G4Q68+b7GCfGJAboOt9Cf0rMB8G
   A1UdIwQYMBaAFJviB1dnHB7AagbeWbSaLd/cGYYuMDUGCCsGAQUFBwEBBCkwJzAl
   BggrBgEFBQcwAYYZaHR0cDovL29jc3AucGtpLmdvb2cvZ3NyMjAyBgNVHR8EKzAp
   MCegJaAjhiFodHRwOi8vY3JsLnBraS5nb29nL2dzcjIvZ3NyMi5jcmwwPwYDVR0g
   BDgwNjA0BgZngQwBAgIwKjAoBggrBgEFBQcCARYcaHR0cHM6Ly9wa2kuZ29vZy9y
   ZXBvc2l0b3J5LzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFAAOCAQEAGoA+Nnn78y6pRjd9XlQWNa7H
   TgiZ/r3RNGkmUmYHPQq6Scti9PEajvwRT2iWTHQr02fesqOqBY2ETUwgZQ+lltoN
   FvhsO9tvBCOIazpswWC9aJ9xju4tWDQH8NVU6YZZ/XteDSGU9YzJqPjY8q3MDxrz
   mqepBCf5o8mw/wJ4a2G6xzUr6Fb6T8McDO22PLRL6u3M4Tzs3A2M1j6bykJYi8wW
   IRdAvKLWZu/axBVbzYmqmwkm5zLSDW5nIAJbELCQCZwMH56t2Dvqofxs6BBcCFIZ
   USpxu6x6td0V7SvJCCosirSmIatj/9dSSVDQibet8q/7UK4v4ZUN80atnZz1yg==
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
2. Выполняем команду: `openssl x509 -noout -text -in intermediate.pem`

   в выводе обращаем внимание на следующие строки:

   ```
   Issuer: OU=GlobalSign Root CA - R2, O=GlobalSign, CN=GlobalSign

   X509v3 Certificate Policies:
       Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.2
         CPS: https://pki.goog/repository/
   ```
3. Открываем в браузере: `https://pki.goog/repository/`

   Скачиваем `GTS Root R2` сертификат по ссылке [DER](https://pki.goog/gtsr2/GTSR2.crt) в файл `GTSR2.crt`
4. Преобразуем скачанный сертификат из двоичного формата DER в текстовый формат PEM:

   `openssl x509 -inform DER -in GTSR2.crt -outform PEM -out GTSR2.pem`

   Файл `GTSR2.pem` будет содержать следующий сертификат:

   ```
   -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
   MIIFWjCCA0KgAwIBAgIQbkepxlqz5yDFMJo/aFLybzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQwFADBH
   MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEiMCAGA1UEChMZR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNlcnZpY2VzIExM
   QzEUMBIGA1UEAxMLR1RTIFJvb3QgUjIwHhcNMTYwNjIyMDAwMDAwWhcNMzYwNjIy
   MDAwMDAwWjBHMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEiMCAGA1UEChMZR29vZ2xlIFRydXN0IFNl
   cnZpY2VzIExMQzEUMBIGA1UEAxMLR1RTIFJvb3QgUjIwggIiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEB
   AQUAA4ICDwAwggIKAoICAQDO3v2m++zsFDQ8BwZabFn3GTXd98GdVarTzTukk3Lv
   CvptnfbwhYBboUhSnznFt+4orO/LdmgUud+tAWyZH8QiHZ/+cnfgLFuv5AS/T3Kg
   GjSY6Dlo7JUle3ah5mm5hRm9iYz+re026nO8/4Piy33B0s5Ks40FnotJk9/BW9Bu
   XvAuMC6C/Pq8tBcKSOWIm8Wba96wyrQD8Nr0kLhlZPdcTK3ofmZemde4wj7I0BOd
   re7kRXuJVfeKH2JShBKzwkCX44ofR5GmdFrS+LFjKBC4swm4VndAoiaYecb+3yXu
   PuWgf9RhD1FLPD+M2uFwdNjCaKH5wQzpoeJ/u1U8dgbuak7MkogwTZq9TwtImoS1
   mKPV+3PBV2HdKFZ1E66HjucMUQkQdYhMvI35ezzUIkgfKtzra7tEscszcTJGr61K
   8YzodDqs5xoic4DSMPclQsciOzsSrZYuxsN2B6ogtzVJV+mSSeh2FnIxZyuWfoqj
   x5RWIr9qS34BIbIjMt/kmkRtWVtd9QCgHJvGeJeNkP+byKq0rxFROV7Z+2et1VsR
   nTKaG73VululycslaVNVJ1zgyjbLiGH7HrfQy+4W+9OmTN6SpdTi3/UGVN4unUu0
   kzCqgc7dGtxRcw1PcOnlthYhGXmy5okLdWTK1au8CcEYof/UVKGFPP0UJAOyh9Ok
   twIDAQABo0IwQDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCAQYwDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zAdBgNV
   HQ4EFgQUu//KjiOfT5nK2+JopqUVJxce2Q4wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEMBQADggIBALZp
   8KZ3/p7uC4Gt4cCpx/k1HUCCq+YEtN/L9x0Pg/B+E02NjO7jMyLDOfxA325BS0JT
   vhaI8dI4XsRomRyYUpOM52jtG2pzegVATX9lO9ZY8c6DR2Dj/5epnGB3GFW1fgiT
   z9D2PGcDFWEJ+YF59exTpJ/JjwGLc8R3dtyDovUMSRqodt6Sm2T4syzFJ9MHwAiA
   pJiS4wGWAqoC7o87xdFtCjMwc3i5T1QWvwsHoaRc5svJXISPD+AVdyx+Jn7axEvb
   pxZ3B7DNdehyQtaVhJ2Gg/LkkM0JR9SLA3DaWsYDQvTtN6LwG1BUSw7YhN4ZKJmB
   R64JGz9I0cNv4rBgF/XuIwKl2gBbbZCr7qLpGzvpx0QnRY5rn/WkhLx3+WuXrD5R
   RaIRpsyF7gpo8j5QOHokYh4XIDdtak23CZvJ/KRY9bb7nE4Yu5UC56GtmwfuNmsk
   0jmGwZODUNKBRqhfYlcsu2xkiAhu7xNUX90txGdj08+JN7+dIPT7eoOboB6BAFDC
   5AwiWVIQ7UNWhwD4FFKnHYuTjKJNRn8nxnGbJN7k2oaLDX5rIMHAnuFl2GqjpuiF
   izoHCBy69Y9Vmhh1fuXsgWbRIXOhNUQLgD1bnF5vKheW0YMjiGZt5obicDIvUiLn
   yOd/xCxgXS/Dr55FBcOEArf9LAhST4Ldo/DUhgkC
   -----END CERTIFICATE-----
   ```
5. Запускаем node.js, указывая маршрут к `GTSR2.pem`:

   `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=../../ssl/api/GTSR2.pem node test.js`

В дальнейшем, можно завести файл `extra_root_ca_certificates.pem`, куда накапливать все нужные дополнительные сертификаты путем конкатенации.

Comment: Спасибо за объяснение! Проверил на  NodeJS`12.10.0`, `12.13.1` - не работает, та же самая ошибка. Не знаю, может в либе ошибка. В версии `8.15.1` - работает, в том числе и без указания сертификата.